# Why is loop not stopping at defined stop point?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

I am working on a quiz for an online course, testing understanding of loops. The problem is:

"Write a function called laugh() that takes one parameter, num that represents the number of “ha”s to return. Such that `console.log(laugh(3));` prints `"hahaha!"`" I solved this using the following loop:

```
function laugh(num) {
  var string = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    string = string + "ha";
  }
  return string + "!";
}
console.log(laugh(3));
```

But out of curiosity, I increased `num` and had the loop return `i` instead of the string:

```
function laugh(num) {
  var string = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    string = string + "ha";
  }
  return i;
}

console.log(laugh(16))
```

This printed `16`. Now I'm confused - shouldn't `i` only reach `15` since one of the conditions of the loop is that `i < num` and `num` is set to `16`?

Comment: The test occurs *after* the increment.

Comment: no, @Plotisateur, post or pre increment makes absolutely no difference in this code

Comment: @Plotisateur Even if it were a pre-increment (`++i`), the effect would be the same - the "test" part is checked after the `final-expression` part is *finished*.

Comment: Suposse `i` is equal to 15, then the condition `15 < 16` will be true and for sure you will still be in the loop. So there is no way the method can return 15. When `i` reach the value `16` then the loop is finished (because `16 < 16` is `false`) and that value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The loop exit condition is `i < num`, so when i >= 16 code `string = string + "ha";` is not executing

Answer (score 0):

In for loop first is increment done after that condition is check. So when "i" incremented to 15 then it checks 15<16, true so continue with rest of the code.
After that, "i" incremented to 16 and checks 16<16, false so came out from the loop.

So, If you print "i", then it will print current value of "i" which is 16

Comment: Thank you. I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

The value of `i` starts  at 0, then it is checked to see if it is less than 16, and lastly, it is increased by 1. On the last iteration, `i` is 15, which satisfies the condition of being less than 15, and then it is incremented. Now, `i` is 16, which is not less than 16, so the for loop finishes with `i` equal to 16.

Answer (score 0):

See, you start i at 0. Walk through the loop step by step. It will execute for i = 0,1,2,3...15. But now you see, the loop executes for *0*. So for any loop of the form (int i = 0; i < num; i++), i reaches num. Convention is to start counting at 0 because that's convention.